# Strip specific characters from string

Tags: php

I've read around and am really struggling with this!

I have the string that contains the word "unfinished", I want to strip out the "un" so it would just print "finished".

How could I do this?

Comment: Check [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace)

Comment: I don't see how this is too localized, stripping parts of a word out can be relevant to others!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = "unfinished";
$newstr = str_replace ( "unfinished","finished", $str );

?>
```

OR

```
<?php

$str = "unfinished";
$newstr = str_replace ( "un","", $str );

?>
```

[str_replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if I do, you can use the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) function (or  the [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php)).

```
$string_you_want_to_search_in = str_replace("unfinished", "finished", $string_you_want_to_search_in);
```

If you want to strip the "un" string from everywhere, just replace "un" for "", like this:

```
$string = str_replace("un", "", $string);
```